# Отладка респонсив дизайна в Chromium

Tags: google-chrome

В моем Chromium 49.0.2623.108 Ubuntu 14.04 есть возможность, при отладке отзывчивого дизайна задавать пользовательские настройки устройств.
Я создал себе несколько штук для удобства ([http://i.imgur.com/9sAJ0KG.png](https://i.imgur.com/9sAJ0KG.png))

Вопросы:

1. А можно ли сделать, так чтобы при выборе девайса из списка `1` масштаб всегда был 100% ?
2. Что это за параметр "Device Pixel Ratio" `3`  и не имеет ли он отношение к пункту выше?

Comment: "Пункт выше" - это тот, что на скриншоте отмечен цифрой 2?

Comment: Нет это "А можно ли сделать, так чтобы при выборе девайса из списка". 1 и 3 номера на картинке по ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Device Pixel Ratio - это количество точек на пиксель, если я не ошибаюсь, от этого зависит качество изображения и прочего. 
А при выборе девайса из списка браузер сам выставляет масштаб так, чтобы выбранные размеры поместили в ваше окошко.

Comment: У меня монитор 1920x1080 pixels
Понятно, что это размеры противоположны размерам iPad-а...
У меня окно отладки расположено справа, и страница имеет вид
http://imgur.com/a/um3OZ

Может, не я первый кому надоело вручную выставлять в 100% - и написали какой-нить плагин ?
У меня обычно выставляети в 75-77%  - смотреть очень неудобно.